# Como deixar o Oracle 12c enterprise com Logs em inglês

Tags: oracle

Bom tarde a todos,

Baixei o oracle 12 Oracle 12c enterprise do site da Oracle com minha conta logada e  o instalador estava todo em portugues porem quando aparece aopção de selecionar o idioma estava portugues e ingles retirei o portugues e salvei, instalou normal o banco porém os erros ORA aparecem em portugues.

Alguem sabe como mudo isso ?

Ja alterei o idioma do windows para ingles como idioma principal ja esta tudo em ingles menos o BD.

Já reinstalei e continua.

Até baixei por vpn com ip no USA.

Não sei mais oque fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

Os arquivos com as mensagens ficam dentro de uma pasta *$ORACLE_HOME/..../mesg*

Remova todos aqueles que não sejam us.

No arquivo *$ORACLE_HOME/install/oraparam.ini* altere a seguinte variável

**NLS_ENABLED=FALSE**

Abs

Answer (score -1):

No arquivo $ORACLE_HOME/install/oraparam.ini altere a seguinte variável

NLS_ENABLED=FALSE

Isso eu conssegui fazer.

mas a outra parte nao tem muitas pastas com esse nome dentro da pasta do oracle.
C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1

tem 22 pastas com esse nome dentro da DBHOME_1 cada uma dentro de uma pasta diferente.

Sabe me dizer qual devo apagar ?